# Can I modify Izpack Uninstaller to delete additional files not created during installtion

Tags: java, izpack, uninstallation

The Izpack uninstaller deletes the installation but not the user folder (and data) I create when the application first runs.

Is there a way to modify the installer to do this  ?
Should I even being doing this, i.e if they are uninstalling the application because they no longer want to use it I should, but if they are just uninstalling the application because they want to install the latest version and they like to uninstall older versions first before doing that I should not remove their user data.

**EDIT**
Should have said Im using Izpack 5beta 11 rather than Izpack 4.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for creating a custom action for the uninstall stage: https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491535/Custom+Actions#id-(CustomActions)-CustomActionsatUninstallationTime(UninstallerListener)

Comment: Okay found some instructions in the Izpack 5 wiki http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=142803064 I will try and give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define custom actions on installation and uninstallation time.

This actions can also be defined using Ant tasks, see http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#ant-actions-installerlistener-and-uninstallerlistener

You especially may find this one useful:

**<uninstall_target>: target to call on uninstallation**
*Targets to perform with this antcall at uninstallation time. The targets should be defined in the given buildfile otherwise an ant exception will be raised. With this target it will be possible to undo the things done at installation time.*
*name: required. The name of the uninstall target.*

Comment: The documentation says 'It is only for developers who are not acquainted with IzPack or it's custom actions' so Im wondering if this is really the easiest solution. I dont want to run ant I just want to run a piece of java code to tidy up.

Comment: I think it's easier to do this using ant, it has all the file management features. But you could also define your own custom Java actions. The ant action is just this: A custom action that calls ant.